# tableView property causes loop

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, crash

I've got a subclass of a UITableViewController and when I call self.tableView in viewDidLoad it crashes and keeps calling the same method. I've transferred it from using storyboards (which was working fine) to just code and now it comes up with this bug. I have a xib file with the UITableViewCell subclass in though.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"AddCell" bundle:nil];

//here
    [self.tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"AddCell"];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancel:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(done:)];

// Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
// self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
// self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}
```

Wondering if anybody has the same problem or if there is a solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It almost seems like the class that contains the above -viewDidLoad implementation already owns the nib. This means every time it wakes, it proceeds to wake itself...

...which then wakes itself, which then wakes itself, which then wakes itself, which then wakes itself, which then wakes itself, which then wakes itself, which then wakes itself, which then wakes itself, which then wakes itself, which then wakes itself, which then wakes itself, which then wakes itself, which then wakes itself, which then wakes itself, which then wakes itself, which then wakes itself, which then wakes itself, ... ... ... ... ...

Could this be your problem?

Comment: dont open a nib in an automatic method, that will then call that automatic method, that will then open another nib... off until you get a stack overflow.

Comment: Ok, do you know why this didn't happen with the storyboard?

Comment: I've fixed it, I think a tableView wasn't automatically getting created! thanks for the responses